# How to understand min/max voltage specification in datasheet?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I've seen different types of min/max voltages in this [datasheet](https://oceanoptics.com/wp-content/uploads/HamamatsuS11510-1006.pdf) and not sure whether I've understood them correctly, so I want to double-check it here.

As shown below, there two types of min/max voltages:

1. Voltage available zone: The voltage provided should fall into this zone, like Reset drain voltage with min=11/max=13, which means the voltage provided to this pin should between 11v and 12v;
2. Voltage threshold zone: It's the uncertain area of the threshold, so voltage provided should be out of this zone, like the high level of Vertical shift clock voltage with min=4/max=8, which means the high level threshold may between 4v and 8v, so the high level of the generated clock should be over 8v.

Do I understand these parameters correctly?

[image]

Comment: Rather than just give a datasheet link, please edit your question to state the device manf., part number and description for readers.

Comment: Why are you assuming point 2? Why should it be higher than 8V?